# How to use cookies to change css <link href="#">?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cookies, href

i'm using this script to change the css link href="#" on the targeted document:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function toggle() {
    var el = document.getElementById("style1");
    if (el.href.match("css/style.css")) {
        el.href = "css/style-b.css";    
    }
    else {
        el.href = "css/style.css";  
    }
}
```

with:

```
<link id="style1" rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="screen">
```

and with button click:

```
<button type="button" onclick="toggle()">Switch</button>
```

but with this click i need to change the css link href="#" to all my .html documents.

how to do this with cookies?

(btw i'm beginner with cookies and js.. so i will need the whole code if can)

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following article explains exactly what you are looking for - the ability to define alternative style sheets, how to switch between them, and to store that choice in a cookie.

http://alistapart.com/article/alternate

Read the article first, but see also the completed example JavaScript file Paul Sowden has written:

http://d.alistapart.com/alternate/styleswitcher.js